# Accordian Dropdown not working on mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, css, html, accordion, dropdown

I have an accordian dropdown menu for FAQ's on my site. On mobile, when the bar is tapped, the accordian drops down and then quickly disappears. I would like the answer section to drop down (possibly with a smooth transition) and stay until the "question" bar is clicked again, or another question bar is clicked. I'm using the following code:

JS

```
    <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('touchstart mousedown', '.acc-btn', function(){
    // If you only want one visible at a time:
    $('.acc-container').find('.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');

    // ^^ 'closes' everything by removing the class selected.
    // Except the one we just clicked, otherwise it wouldn't toggle—
    // the class would get removed and added back two lines down.


    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

  });

});</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="acc-container">

<div class="acc-btn"><h1>What is Company?</h1></div>

<div class="acc-content">

<div class="acc-content-inner">

<p> Answer blah blah</p>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.acc-container {
  width:90%;
  margin:30px auto 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.acc-btn { 
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
font-weight:lighter;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-bottom:3px;
height: 100%;
cursor: pointer;

}


.acc-content {
  max-height:0px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#C9C8C8;
  color:#000000;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out 0s;*/
}

.selected + .acc-content {
    max-height: 700px;
}

.acc-content-inner {
  padding:30px;
}

.open {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: can u make a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy fix is to replace

```
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown',
```

With

```
$(document).on('click',
```

## Reason

The code you've written attaches the open/close logic to *both* the touchstart and mousedown events. The problem is that on most current mobile devices a physical touch is used to trigger both touch events **and** mouse events. This is to improve compatibility with sites that were not built to be touch friendly.

This is causing you trouble because as soon as one runs, the other follows undoing what you've just done.

You can use this behavior to your advantage though because touch events are also registered as clicks, which means handling a click event will cover both mouse and touch based devices with one call.  Otherwise you'll have to create logic to check if the touch event has been handled before running the mouse event and vice versa.

This does change your behavior slightly because click does not exactly copy mousedown (click requires the button to be both pressed and released before firing) but is the more standard behavior and, I think, what you're looking for.

Comment: That works, thank you! And thank you for the thorough explanation, I love learning WHY something works, not just how. :)

Comment: Glad  it worked @Jennifer. I wouldn't hold it against you if you marked the question answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the event is fired twice, so what you could do is to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree:

```
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown', '.acc-btn', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    /* ... REST OF THE CODE ... */
});
```